# Storing time based data and identify gaps

Tags: sql, nosql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have few million sensors which continuously perform health checks and send data every `5 minutes` to a server. My task is to store these data points and generate a report every hour about the ones which failed to report.

Questions:

- Which database is optimal for such operations? (sql / nosql) and which one specifically? The indexes will be strings.
- What can be an optimal query for the above chosen database

Example data:

```
"point1"    "12-2-19T00:00"
"point2"    "12-2-19T00:00"
"point1"    "12-2-19T00:05" #missing point2
"point1"    "12-2-19T00:10"
"point2"    "12-2-19T00:10"
```

I need to find point2

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT point, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d-%m-%yT%H:%M', dt) dt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), points AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT point FROM temp
), times AS (
  SELECT dt
  FROM (SELECT MIN(dt) min_dt, MAX(dt) max_dt FROM temp), 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_dt, max_dt, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) dt
)
SELECT 
  point, 
  FORMAT_DATETIME('%d-%m-%yT%H:%M', DATETIME(dt)) dt, 
  IF(t.point IS NULL, 'missing', 'ok') status
FROM times CROSS JOIN points 
LEFT JOIN temp t USING(dt, point)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'point1' point, '12-2-19T00:00' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'point2', '12-2-19T00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'point1', '12-2-19T00:05' UNION ALL -- #missing point2
  SELECT 'point1', '12-2-19T00:10' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'point2', '12-2-19T00:10' 
), temp AS (
  SELECT point, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d-%m-%yT%H:%M', dt) dt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), points AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT point FROM temp
), times AS (
  SELECT dt
  FROM (SELECT MIN(dt) min_dt, MAX(dt) max_dt FROM temp), 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_dt, max_dt, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) dt
)
SELECT 
  point, 
  FORMAT_DATETIME('%d-%m-%yT%H:%M', DATETIME(dt)) dt, 
  IF(t.point IS NULL, 'missing', 'ok') status
FROM times CROSS JOIN points 
LEFT JOIN temp t USING(dt, point)
-- ORDER BY dt, point
```

with result

```
Row point   dt              status   
1   point1  12-02-19T00:00  ok   
2   point2  12-02-19T00:00  ok   
3   point1  12-02-19T00:05  ok   
4   point2  12-02-19T00:05  missing  
5   point1  12-02-19T00:10  ok   
6   point2  12-02-19T00:10  ok
```

Comment: @Devaroop - did you have chance to try? consider voting  up and accept if applicable :o)